# Plotting bar chart with lattice

Tags: r, lattice

I have a bunch of data in .csv arranged like so

```
data        value        group
1/1/2012    a            1
1/1/2012    b            2
1/1/2012    c            3
1/1/2012    d            4
1/1/2012    e            5
2/1/2012    f            1 
2/1/2012    g            2
2/1/2012    h            3
2/1/2012    i            4
2/1/2012    j            5
3/1/2012    k            1
3/1/2012    ...          ...
```

so it's 5 entries (5 groups) per month and I need to plot the difference between the value of the 5th entry and 1st entry per month as a bar chart, ie e-a, j-f etc.  Is there a way I can do this in the barchart command in lattice without having to apply the transformation prior either in csv or R studio.  Fairly new at this thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to calculate the differences before plotting?

Comment: No. You need to apply the transformation to your data. Lattice is a plotting library, not a data manipulation library. You must feed it the data you want to plot. Also i assume value is a number in your real data because "e-a" would be hard to plot otherwise.

Comment: no particular reason, how would I perform this transformation in R studio and not in the csv